# How to replace special character in java

Tags: java, string, character

I have a problem:

I copied more value (for example 23700  5000.2  0.000)  from Excel file in a file .txt.

When I read in java this value stored in .txt file, and i copy this in another file .txt (with java), the result is the same:

23700   5000.2  0.000਍㈀㌀㜀㄀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ　⸀㌀㌀㔀ഀ
23720   5067.7  0.670਍㈀㌀㜀㌀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ㄀⸀　　㔀ഀ
23740   5067.7  1.340਍㈀㌀㜀㔀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ㄀⸀㘀㜀㔀ഀ
23760   5067.7  2.010਍㈀㌀㜀㜀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ㈀⸀㌀㐀㔀ഀ
23780   5067.7  2.680਍㈀㌀㜀㤀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ㌀⸀　㄀㔀ഀ
23800   5067.7  3.351਍㈀㌀㠀㄀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ㌀⸀㘀㠀㘀ഀ
23820   5067.7  4.021਍㈀㌀㠀㌀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ㐀⸀㌀㔀㘀ഀ
23840   5067.7  4.691਍㈀㌀㠀㔀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ㔀⸀　㈀㘀ഀ
23860   5067.7  5.361਍㈀㌀㠀㜀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ㔀⸀㘀㤀㘀ഀ
23880   5067.7  6.031਍㈀㌀㠀㤀　ऀ㔀　㘀㜀⸀㜀ऀ㘀⸀㌀㘀㘀ഀ
23900   5067.7  6.701਍㈀㌀㤀㄀　ऀ㠀㌀㘀㄀⸀㘀ऀ㜀⸀　㌀㜀ഀ
23920   9577.0  7.372਍㈀㌀㤀㌀　ऀ㤀㔀㜀㜀⸀　ऀ㜀⸀㜀　㜀ഀ
23940   9577.0  8.042਍㈀㌀㤀㔀　ऀ㤀㔀㜀㜀⸀　ऀ㠀⸀㌀㜀㜀ഀ
23960   9577.0  8.712਍㈀㌀㤀㜀　ऀ㤀㔀㜀㜀⸀　ऀ㤀⸀　㐀㜀ഀ
23980   9577.0  9.382਍㈀㌀㤀㤀　ऀ㤀㔀㜀㜀⸀　ऀ㤀⸀㜀㄀㜀ഀ

Can I eliminate this wrong character?

THX To all

Comment: I suggest you read the Excel file as an excel file. e.g. use the POI API

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. Not knowing the character set and encoding of a ".txt" file is data loss. When you do know, you specify it in your file/stream/whatever reader (usually, it's an argument to the constructor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that today, text files are not all ascii. They can be utf-8, latin-1, utf-16, etc

The problem is likely that in your copying you are either opening the text file with the wrong text format, or writing it with the wrong text format. To open correctly, use

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"utf-16");
```

substitute your file format for utf-16

For writing, use an `OutputStreamWriter` on a `FileOutputStream`

Comment: I'm trying to think of a day when text files were ASCII. On the Digital Equipment Corp PDP-11 with the RSX-11 operating system, I think might they have been. (I didn't program in APL.) On my Corona Data Systems IBM-compatible PC with MS-DOS 1.25, they were CP 437. ╟Box drawing characters were really hot back then╢ (We still use them today in Windows `tree /f`)